# Pythonic way to combine two FOR loops and an IF statement?

Tags: python

I have this loop:

```
for e in elements:
    for h in hs:
        if h.complete and e.date < h.date:
            print('----completed at time----',)
```

Is there a way to write it in one line or in a Pythonic way?

Comment: There is, but I don't see why you have to.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with two `for loops`. You could reduce it into one line, but it wouldn't be as readable.

Comment: `l = ['---completed at time----' for h in hs for e in elements if h.complete and e.date < h.date]; print(*l, sep='\n')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to write it in one line

Yes.

> or in a Pythonic way?

What you have currently is already the most Pythonic way, no need to change anything here.

Answer (score 3):

There's a plethora of different ways to shrink this to fewer lines -- but most of them will be less readable. For example:

- not-really-list comprehension: `[print('whatever') for e in elements for h in hs if e.date < h.date]`
- list comprehension: `for p in [sth(e, h) for e in elements for h in hs if e.date < h.date]: print(p)`
- using `itertools.product`:

  ```
  for e, h in product(elements, hs):
      if h.complete and e.date < h.date:
          print('whatever')
  ```
- same as above but with `filter`:

  ```
  for e, h in filter(lambda e, h: h.complete and e.date < h.date, product(elements, hs)):
      print('whatever')
  ```

*Edit*: My personal preference lies with the first `product` example, which (while only shaving a single line off of the original code) is better at telegraphing what the code actually does.